# How to use ReactiveCommand?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, reactiveui

I have a viewmodel that uses ReactiveCommand:

```
public ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> Command { get; }

public MyViewModel()
{
    Command = ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit>.Create(MyMethod);
}
```

And bind it to a button:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Button Content="Press me" 
    Command="{Binding Command, Mode=OneTime}"
    Margin="0,0,5,0"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

I bind view to viewmodel like this (most convenient way in my case):

```
myView.DataContext = new MyViewModel();
```

When I press the button MyMethod is executed and right after execution of the last operator in MyMethod my application crashes with:

> InvalidOperationException: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

```
  StackTrace:
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.VerifyAccess()
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.GetValue(DependencyProperty dp)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.get_Command()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.UpdateCanExecute()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnCanExecuteChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.CanExecuteChangedEventManager.HandlerSink.OnCanExecuteChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at ReactiveUI.ReactiveCommand.OnCanExecuteChanged()
   at ReactiveUI.ReactiveCommand`2.<.ctor>b__9_6(Boolean _)
   at System.Reactive.AnonymousSafeObserver`1.OnNext(T value) in D:\a\1\s\Rx.NET\Source\src\System.Reactive\AnonymousSafeObserver.cs:line 54
   at System.Reactive.Linq.ObservableImpl.RefCount`1._.OnNext(TSource value) in D:\a\1\s\Rx.NET\Source\src\System.Reactive\Linq\Observable\RefCount.cs:line 66
   at System.Reactive.Subjects.FastImmediateObserver`1.EnsureActive(Int32 count) in D:\a\1\s\Rx.NET\Source\src\System.Reactive\Subjects\ReplaySubject.cs:line 893
   at System.Reactive.Subjects.FastImmediateObserver`1.EnsureActive() in D:\a\1\s\Rx.NET\Source\src\System.Reactive\Subjects\ReplaySubject.cs:line 753
   at System.Reactive.Subjects.ReplaySubject`1.ReplayBase.OnNext(T value) in D:\a\1\s\Rx.NET\Source\src\System.Reactive\Subjects\ReplaySubject.cs:line 276
   at System.Reactive.Subjects.ReplaySubject`1.OnNext(T value) in D:\a\1\s\Rx.NET\Source\src\System.Reactive\Subjects\ReplaySubject.cs:line 167
   at System.Reactive.Linq.ObservableImpl.AsObservable`1._.OnNext(TSource value) in D:\a\1\s\Rx.NET\Source\src\System.Reactive\Linq\Observable\AsObservable.cs:line 32
   at System.Reactive.Linq.ObservableImpl.DistinctUntilChanged`2._.OnNext(TSource value) in D:\a\1\s\Rx.NET\Source\src\System.Reactive\Linq\Observable\DistinctUntilChanged.cs:line 79
   at System.Reactive.Linq.ObservableImpl.CombineLatest`3._.SecondObserver.OnNext(TSecond value) in D:\a\1\s\Rx.NET\Source\src\System.Reactive\Linq\Observable\CombineLatest.cs:line 189
   at System.Reactive.Linq.ObservableImpl.RefCount`1._.OnNext(TSource value) in D:\a\1\s\Rx.NET\Source\src\System.Reactive\Linq\Observable\RefCount.cs:line 66
   at System.Reactive.Subjects.FastImmediateObserver`1.EnsureActive(Int32 count) in D:\a\1\s\Rx.NET\Source\src\System.Reactive\Subjects\ReplaySubject.cs:line 893
   at System.Reactive.Subjects.FastImmediateObserver`1.EnsureActive() in D:\a\1\s\Rx.NET\Source\src\System.Reactive\Subjects\ReplaySubject.cs:line 753
   at System.Reactive.Subjects.ReplaySubject`1.ReplayBase.OnNext(T value) in D:\a\1\s\Rx.NET\Source\src\System.Reactive\Subjects\ReplaySubject.cs:line 276
   at System.Reactive.Subjects.ReplaySubject`1.OnNext(T value) in D:\a\1\s\Rx.NET\Source\src\System.Reactive\Subjects\ReplaySubject.cs:line 167
   at System.Reactive.Linq.ObservableImpl.AsObservable`1._.OnNext(TSource value) in D:\a\1\s\Rx.NET\Source\src\System.Reactive\Linq\Observable\AsObservable.cs:line 32
   at System.Reactive.Linq.ObservableImpl.DistinctUntilChanged`2._.OnNext(TSource value) in D:\a\1\s\Rx.NET\Source\src\System.Reactive\Linq\Observable\DistinctUntilChanged.cs:line 79
   at System.Reactive.Linq.ObservableImpl.Concat`1._.OnNext(TSource value) in D:\a\1\s\Rx.NET\Source\src\System.Reactive\Linq\Observable\Concat.cs:line 34
   at System.Reactive.Linq.ObservableImpl.Select`2.Selector._.OnNext(TSource value) in D:\a\1\s\Rx.NET\Source\src\System.Reactive\Linq\Observable\Select.cs:line 49
   at System.Reactive.Linq.ObservableImpl.Scan`2._.OnNext(TSource value) in D:\a\1\s\Rx.NET\Source\src\System.Reactive\Linq\Observable\Scan.cs:line 50
   at System.Reactive.SafeObserver`1.OnNext(TSource value) in D:\a\1\s\Rx.NET\Source\src\System.Reactive\Internal\SafeObserver.cs:line 50
   at System.Reactive.ScheduledObserver`1.Dispatch(ICancelable cancel) in D:\a\1\s\Rx.NET\Source\src\System.Reactive\Internal\ScheduledObserver.cs:line 93
   at System.Reactive.Concurrency.Scheduler.<>c.<ScheduleLongRunning>b__73_0(Action`1 a, ICancelable c) in D:\a\1\s\Rx.NET\Source\src\System.Reactive\Concurrency\Scheduler.Simple.cs:line 78
   at System.Reactive.Concurrency.DefaultScheduler.LongRunning.<>c__DisplayClass1_0`1.<ScheduleLongRunning>b__0(Object arg) in D:\a\1\s\Rx.NET\Source\src\System.Reactive\Concurrency\DefaultScheduler.cs:line 165
   at System.Reactive.Concurrency.ConcurrencyAbstractionLayerImpl.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<StartThread>b__0() in D:\a\1\s\Rx.NET\Source\src\System.Reactive\Concurrency\ConcurrencyAbstractionLayerImpl.cs:line 56
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Am I using ReactiveCommand wrong or is it a bug in ReactiveUI?

I'm able to reproduce this error in minimal WPF application that just call ReactiveCommand with empty method.

Comment: Please show what MyMethod is doing, this error happens because your command is doing something in the worng thread, you can try passing outputScheduler argument, you can  do _ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit>.Create(MyMethod,outputScheduler: RxApp.MainThreadScheduler);_

Comment: It throws the same exception even if MyMethod is empty. Unfortunately adding `outputScheduler: RxApp.MainThreadScheduler` doesn't help.

Comment: What happends if you remove Mode=OneTime ?

Comment: I see your point but it doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just had to install ReactiveUI.WPF NuGet package.

Really would love better documentation for ReactiveUI.

Comment: I was almost slitting my wrists.. thanks, you're a lifesaver :D

Comment: For their defense, there is now a warning in debug console during startup.